# Reset pin graphic when infobox closes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some simple Google Maps (API v3) code that changes the icon to orange when a particular marker is clicked and the infobox opens. The code also notices if an infobox was already open and if so, resets the marker icon on that old infobox.

However, I can't figure out how to reset the marker icon back to the default if the infobox is simply closed.

I use just one InfoBox and fill it with the details each time a marker is clicked:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {

        if(previousMarker) {
            // if marker icon was changed before, change it back to default
            previousMarker.setIcon('/img/location_pin.png');
        }
        ib.close();               // close infobox that is already open
        ib.setOptions(opt[i]);    // set new options for the infobox
        ib.open(map, this);       // open it on this marker

        // and change marker color to orange
        marker.setIcon('/img/location_pin-orange.png');

        previousMarker = marker;  // remember marker for next time

        map.panTo(markerData[i].latLng);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

How can I have the markers on the map (or just `previousMarker`, really) go back to the default color when the infobox is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset your marker options inside the callback for the `closeclick` event on the InfoWindow.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(ib, 'closeclick', function(){ 
    // add code to reset marker options 
});
```

See [API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) for all events associated with the InfoWindow object.

If you are using the InfoBox library, the events are still the same so the same event listener can be applied: [API reference for InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html)

Comment: Thank you. I added a loop to walk through all my markers and reset their icons and that did the trick.